# Bind volumes that contains mount points mounted within docker container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

I have a **privileged** docker container that will mount a custom File System with FUSE.

It is achieved by bind mounting `/dev`,`/sys` from the host to the container and running some custom software which accessed block device e.g. `/dev/sdX` **inside the container** to mount a custom FS on some mount point, let's say `/mnt/some_mountpoint_inside_the_container` (everything still happens **inside the container**).

Now, I would like to access this mount point that are mounted inside the docker container ***from the host*** but with no avail. So far, I have tried:

1. In my `docker-compose.yaml`, I defined a (binded) volume from host to container, e.g.:

```
...
    volumes:
    - /mnt/mountpoint_at_host:/mnt/some_mountpoint_inside_the_container
...
```

Then, I have FUSE mounted the custom FS inside the container on `/mnt/some_mountpoint_inside_the_container`. It seems that even I have added files in `/mnt/mountpoint_at_host` on my host, changes are not reflected within the container (i.e. `ls -al /mnt/some_mountpoint_inside_the_container` inside the container returns nothing). Only AFTER I have un-mounted `/mnt/some_mountpoint_inside_the_container` within the container, the created files on the host can now be found on the container.

2. I have also tried to bind mount a parent folder:

```
...
    volumes:
    - /mnt/mountpoint_at_host:/mnt/parent_folder
...
```

Then I created a folder on my host: `mkdir -p /mnt/mountpoint_at_host/the_real_mntpt`.

I have then again, FUSE mounted the custom FS in the docker container on:
`/mnt/parent_folder/the_real_mntpt`.

But still, changes on the host are not reflected on the container side, or the underlining block device.

Is there any way I can access to the mount point that are mounted within the container from the host? I have thought of methods like creating NFS service within the container after I have FUSE mounted the FS, and then exposing the NFS port to the host. But it seems a bit inefficient.

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu with `docker.io`/`docker-compose` from `apt-get`. The container itself is a CentOS 8.

Comment: Would it be easier to run this process directly on the host, rather than trying to bypass most of Docker's isolation controls?

Comment: @DavidMaze There are some libraries that would cause issues with the host, and the software requires specific Linux distributions, that's why I have to use containers.